# How do I subtract the value of a javascript variable when form element is unchecked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

Note, this isn't my code, or the actual code in the form.  This is just my testing version, but does represent what I want to do.

Given the following code, how can I get the script to subtract the passed value when the checkbox is unselected:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

    <head>
        <title>form test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function updateAmount(amount) {
                parseInt(amount);
                if ($('#amount').val()) {
                    parseInt(amount);
                    amount = amount + parseInt($('#amount').val());
                }
                $('#amount').val(amount);
                alert('Amount: ' + $('#amount').val());
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="" method="post" name="form-test">
            <input onclick="updateAmount(150)" class="inputbox" id="reservationfee0"
            value="Registration Fee" type="checkbox" />
            <strong>$150</strong>Reservation Fee</form>
    </body>

</html>
```

As it stands, whoever coded the function didn't take into account that people might check and uncheck that box before they submit the form (which includes more fields and other numbers that get added into the amount variable before submission).  There has been a couple of reports of over-charges due to this, so I need to figure out how to stop it from happening, but I know very little about javascript/jquery.

Comment: Do you want to subtract 150 if its unchecked and add 150 when its checked?

Comment: You're using parseInt incorrectly in your example. Also, you are referencing an element with an ID of 'amount', yet no such element exists in your example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try :

```
function updateAmount(amount) {
    $amount = $('#amount'); // cache for later use
    if ($('#reservationfee0').is(':checked')) {
        $amount.val(parseInt($amount.val(), 10) + amount);
    } else {
        $amount.val(parseInt($amount.val(), 10) - amount);
    }
}​
```

**[Working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/manseuk/JCcuk/)**

this checks if the `checkbox` is checked using [`.is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) if it is then the amount is added to the current value if not its subtracted.

Also note that `parseInt` takes a second parameter - `radix` its recommended that you include this value to be certain of results ... [docs for parseInt here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)

Comment: This, with some extra mods to work with the rest of the actual form, solved the problem perfectly.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

can you try this

```
      function updateAmount(amount) {
            parseInt(amount);
            if ($('#reservationfee0').prop('checked')) {
                amount = amount + parseFloat($('#amount').val());
            }
         else{
              amount = parseFloat($('#amount').val())-amount;
         }
            $('#amount').val(amount);
            alert('Amount: ' + $('#amount').val());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

What we can do is define a variable just above the function which we can set for the first time. The code goes as follows:

```
       var chk=1;
       function updateAmount(amount) {
            parseInt(amount);
            if ($('#amount').val() && document.getElementById('reservationfee0').checked && chk==1) {
                chk=0;
                parseInt(amount);
                amount = amount + parseInt($('#amount').val());
            }
            $('#amount').val(amount);
            alert('Amount: ' + $('#amount').val());
        }
```